# Exploring the view tree in Android

Tags: android, android-view

It's maybe a bit abstract but I'd like to know if some of you have a decent solution to that problem:

**I have a complicated layout and I need to find ALL the instances of a certain type of view.**

I have few solutions but I find none of them perfect and I'd like to know if there is another way or a way to improve them.

**MY FIRST OPTION**

We can iterate in the view tree with `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()` and then check with `instanceof` like in lots of SO answers.

```
for (int i = 0; i<parentContainer.getChildCount(); i++){
    View child = getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof BlaBla){
        // Do something wonderful
    }
}
```

It is highly inefficient because I have these instances in many places and in particular in nested places so I need to make this method recursive.

**MY SECOND OPTION**

It would be to work with dynamic tags or ids and use `findViewById` or `findViewWithTag`. But the issue is that it makes something more to configure and as always it makes the software more complicated.

> So my question is: how can I do a complete search in the view tree in
>   order to find all instances of a component without doing the search
>   myself (because it would be probably be very inefficient)? Is that
>   somehow possible?

Comment: "It is highly inefficient" -- cache your results. "Is that somehow possible?" -- not that I am aware of.

Comment: Ok if @CommonsWare is not aware of that, it is just not possible hahaha. Good point for caching. I, nevertheless, appreciate the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm not sure second option is possible as in this case you'll need to create this views in runtime and assign some generated ID with some bit mask to recognize them later. If to create your views from layout you will end up with traversing tree view and assigning these special IDs which is pretty much accends to 1st option.

In my project I also have to dynamically apply colors to some views and I do it without recursion. Pattern is following:

```
ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
views.add(getWindow().getDecorView());

    do {
      View v = views.remove(0);
       if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
           ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) v;
           for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
             views.add(group.getChildAt(i));
           }
       }
       if (v instanceof MyCustomView) {
         //do whatever you need here
       }
    } while(!views.isEmpty());
```

So you get rid of using recursion and replace it with own stack and iteration through it. This solution quite efficient especially if you can skip things like ListView, RecyclerView.

Comment: That is a very nice answer, yes. However, still have to do the search yourself. I'll let the question opened a bit longer and I'll validate your option if no one come with a revolutionary one ;)

Comment: BTW just recalled another possible option ViewGroup has bunch of methods which may be useful for you: `ViewGroup.findNamedViews()`  and `ViewGroup.findViewsWithText()`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's proper way of using it but... You can set `android:transitionName="string_id"` on views and then try to use this method.